Getting failed results on Brand campaigns on our Twilio sub-accounts
I was having difficulty in getting A2P approval on our sub-accounts brand campaign. The error shows: (1) The campaign submission has been reviewed and rejected due to issues verifying the Call to Action (CTA) provided for the campaign. (2) Your A2P Campaign registration with TCR failed. (3) The campaign submission has been reviewed and it was rejected because of unverifiable website.
I have read the information on the site, but still i could not figured out any resolution. Could anyone assist me that can help me in getting A2P approval without encountering those errors.I would really appreciate it.

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

Your campaign was rejected because the Twilio team was not able to verify the opt-in  (consent) CTA. If you have mentioned a website form for opt-in, you have to make sure that website is accessible and you have the consent checkbox.
